# excel vba syntax for evaluate("min(index(row

Tags: vba, excel

from another post, [combine rows with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421007/) I received answer, but having problem parsing the evaluate line.

```
mr = Application.Evaluate("MIN(INDEX(ROW(1:" & rw & ")+(('" & wsn & "'!B1:B" & rw & "<>'" & wsn & "'!B" & rw & ")+('" & wsn & "'!C1:C" & rw & "<>'" & wsn & "'!C" & rw & "))*1E+99, , ))")
```

1. I am initially stuck on the part

   `INDEX(ROW(1:" & rw & ")`

I know that Row function provides the row number but syntax above is what range 1:rw or ??

2. The + plus sign are logical OR statements?

If someone can provide a simpler example of MIN(INDEX(ROW(... with only a few arguments and explanation that would be very helpful.

Comment: I think you have a problem with **double quotes**.  Please update your post with the equation you would actually see in a worksheet cell.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever in doubt, debug the formula in the Immediate window. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim wsn As String

    rw = 1      '<~~ Giving them some fictitious values. Give actual value if you have one
    wsn = "Sid" '<~~ Giving them some fictitious values. Give actual value if you have one

    sFormula = "MIN(INDEX(ROW(1:" & _
               rw & _
               ")+(('" & _
               wsn & _
               "'!B1:B" & _
               rw & _
               "<>'" & _
               wsn & _
               "'!B" & _
               rw & _
               ")+('" & _
               wsn & _
               "'!C1:C" & _
               rw & _
               "<>'" & _
               wsn & _
               "'!C" & _
               rw & _
               "))*1E+99, , ))"

    Debug.Print sFormula

    'mr = Application.Evaluate(sFormula)
End Sub
```

[image]

The formula will be clear to you then :)

You can even copy that formula to a new sheet to test it.

[image]