# More efficient way to combine two worksheets data

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-2010

I've got a working method for combining two sheets of data; however, it is a bit slower than I had hoped.  I am wondering if anyone knows of a faster way to combine the data.

I compare two sheets with roughly 700 and 400 rows, respectively. Data in sheet 1 contains unique aircraft flight numbers along with a separate row for each leg of that flight (one mission number may have 5 or 6 "legs" of a flight, each on its own row).  Sheet 2 contains that same mission number, but tells me how many passengers and how much cargo (called "lifts"), if any, are on certain legs.  Only those legs with "lifts" are listed in this sheet.  Some lifts stay onboard for multiple legs.  The empty legs are not shown.

I need to combine the two so that the passenger and cargo information from Sheet 2 is added to the correct leg of the mission on Sheet 1.  This gives me a complete, detailed view of that mission.  I take this data and show it on a graphical map I created in Excel.

Here is the code I use, currently:

```
Sub combineDataTest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long, lastRow2 As Long

Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Missions")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Passengers and Cargo")

ws2.Columns("H:J").Cells.Clear

lastRow = findLastRow("Passengers and Cargo") 'calls a function that returns the last row
lastRow2 = findLastRow("Full Missions") 'calls a function that returns the last row

' Add column names on mission sheet
ws2.Range("H1").Value = "LIFT CODE"
ws2.Range("I1").Value = "LIFT PASSENGERS"
ws2.Range("J1").Value = "LIFT CARGO"

For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 2 To lastRow2

        ' If the mission numbers match
        If ws3.Range("A" & i).Value = Left(ws2.Range("D" & j).Value, 9) And _
        ws2.Range("E" & j).Value >= ws3.Range("C" & i).Value And _
        ws2.Range("E" & j).Value <= ws3.Range("D" & i).Value - 1 Then

            If ws2.Range("H" & j).Value = "" Then
                ws2.Range("H" & j).Value = ws3.Range("Q" & i).Value
                ws2.Range("I" & j).Value = ws3.Range("O" & i).Value
                ws2.Range("J" & j).Value = ws3.Range("P" & i).Value
            Else
                ws2.Range("H" & j).Value = ws2.Range("H" & j).Value & ", " & ws3.Range("Q" & i).Value
                ws2.Range("I" & j).Value = ws2.Range("I" & j).Value + ws3.Range("O" & i).Value
                ws2.Range("J" & j).Value = ws2.Range("J" & j).Value + ws3.Range("P" & i).Value
            End If

        End If

    Next j
Next i
```

If you have a better idea of how to run through the code, I would greatly appreciate it.  I'm not sure if running it through arrays would be faster or if this is just as good as it is going to get.

EDIT: Here are some example tables of data.  This is not real data.

Full Missions:

```
ICAO | LONG   | LAT   | MISSION_ACFT  |LEG| ARRIVAL          | DEPART
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC155894_C26 | 1 | 20-JUN-2015 1101 | 20-JUN-2015 1101
KGTR | -88.58 | 33.43 | ABC155894_C26 | 2 | 20-JUN-2015 1433 | 20-JUN-2015 1348
KNGU | -76.28 | 36.93 | ABC155894_C26 | 3 | 20-JUN-2015 1800 | 20-JUN-2015 1715
KCLT | -80.93 | 35.2  | ABC155894_C26 | 4 | 20-JUN-2015 1940 | 20-JUN-2015 1910
KGSO | -79.93 | 36.1  | ABC155894_C26 | 5 | 20-JUN-2015 2035 | 20-JUN-2015 2005
KRDU | -78.78 | 35.87 | ABC155894_C26 | 6 | 20-JUN-2015 2130 | 20-JUN-2015 2100
KNGU | -76.28 | 36.93 | ABC155894_C26 | 7 | 20-JUN-2015 2235 | 20-JUN-2015 2205
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC155894_C26 | 8 | 20-JUN-2015 2300 | 20-JUN-2015 2300
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC156469_C26 | 1 | 26-JUN-2015 1101 | 26-JUN-2015 1101
KVQQ | -81.87 | 30.22 | ABC156469_C26 | 2 | 26-JUN-2015 1408 | 26-JUN-2015 1323
KHST | -80.38 | 25.48 | ABC156469_C26 | 3 | 26-JUN-2015 1616 | 26-JUN-2015 1531
KMCF | -82.52 | 27.83 | ABC156469_C26 | 4 | 26-JUN-2015 1748 | 26-JUN-2015 1703
KVQQ | -81.87 | 30.22 | ABC156469_C26 | 5 | 26-JUN-2015 1910 | 26-JUN-2015 1825
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC156469_C26 | 6 | 26-JUN-2015 2121 | 26-JUN-2015 2121
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC156733_C26 | 1 | 27-JUN-2015 1533 | 27-JUN-2015 1533
KDAA | -77.17 | 38.7  | ABC156733_C26 | 2 | 27-JUN-2015 1643 | 27-JUN-2015 1558
KCHS | -80.03 | 32.88 | ABC156733_C26 | 3 | 27-JUN-2015 1916 | 27-JUN-2015 1831
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC156733_C26 | 4 | 27-JUN-2015 2038 | 27-JUN-2015 2038
KRIC | -77.32 | 37.5  | ABC156773_C26 | 1 | 28-JUN-2015 1113 | 28-JUN-2015 1113
KNCA | -77.43 | 34.7  | ABC156773_C26 | 2 | 28-JUN-2015 1246 | 28-JUN-2015 1201
KLSF | -84.98 | 32.32 | ABC156773_C26 | 3 | 28-JUN-2015 1526 | 28-JUN-2015 1441
```

Passengers and Cargo: (Excess data removed for space savings)

```
MISSION   | B | ONL|OFFL| E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |PAX|CAR|LIFT ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC155894 |   |  1 |  2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |100| E
ABC155894 |   |  3 |  4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |155| A
ABC155894 |   |  4 |  5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |155| B
ABC155894 |   |  5 |  6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |155| C
ABC155894 |   |  6 |  7 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |155| D
ABC156469 |   |  2 |  3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |220| A
ABC156469 |   |  3 |  4 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |220| B
ABC156469 |   |  4 |  5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |220| C
ABC156733 |   |  2 |  3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |0  | A
ABC156773 |   |  2 |  3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2 |0  | A
```

Comment: So, all the data on sheet 2 WILL be on Sheet1? Also will each flight number from sheet2 match one cell/row or multiple cells/rows on sheet1?

Comment: SO is generally meant for problems or errors with code, I think its a better fit to ask your question at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is the SE place for reviewing code and giving improvement tips :)

Comment: You have nested loops so you are making 280,000 comparisons.  Can you sort the worksheets by mission number?  You would then be able to work down the two worksheets sequentially.

Comment: Tim - the flight number and all leg numbers are on the Full Missions sheet.  The lifts are listed on the Passengers sheet along with what flight number and what leg(s) they are on.

Comment: Dragon - I understand.  I was not aware of code review. I will give them a shot as well.

Comment: Tony - they are currently both sorted in order, but the passenger sheet does not contain all legs on the mission. Just those with passengers.

Comment: @ineverfinishanyth Just make sure to read our [help centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) before posting anything. :)

Comment: It does not matter that the passenger sheet does not contain all legs. Working down two lists that are in the same sequence looking for matches is not difficult.

Comment: From your code, I deduce that column A of "Passengers and Cargo" contains a 9-character Mission Identifier while column D of "Full Missions" contains a Leg Identifier which starts with the Mission Identifier. But having the same Mission Identifiers is not enough for a match. There is also a range check of column E of "Full Missions" against columns C and D of "Passengers and Cargo".  You give no information about this range check. Without more information on the range check, and perhaps the two keys, I do not see how anyone can help.

Comment: You do not have the reputation to post images of your data.  You could describe the data, use the code facility to build tables or post the data elsewhere and provide a link.

Comment: I have generated some data that matches your description. It is not particularly good data because I know nothing about columns E, C and D so there are no matches.  However, your macro took 12 seconds to process this data.  It would take longer if there were matches but this does not seem too bad for something you only run once per day.

Comment: Tony - you are correct. I can see how the data is hard to visualize. I'll post some example tables tomorrow from work. I'll edit my original post to add them.

Comment: @ineverfinishanyth. I will study the tables with interest.  The "@ yourname" is not necessary because you are automatically told about comments against your questions.  But the people posting comments are not told about your replies unless you include their name preceeded by an @.  Note: there must not be a space between the @ and the name.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I added example data for the tables.  This set of code is run as part of a larger set multiple times a day by 15+ individuals.  I created a map of mission routes in Excel and it plots the data based on this information.  As new missions are created, the map needs to be refreshed to reflect that information.  We schedule 40+ requests for airlift every day.  That's why I'm hoping to shrink down the runtime so much.  It'll help a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally much faster to

- read your data into VBA Arrays (can be done in a single step)
- iterate through the arrays and collect the desired data
- create an array of the desired results in the desired order
- write this array to a worksheet (also can be done in a single step)

Depending on the complexity of the data, it may be beneficial to create a User Defined Object (Class) with the desired properties, and then collect these objects into a Collection as the source for the Results array.

See [Chip Pearson's "Introduction to Classes"](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)  for more information on User Defined Objects.

An example of using this approach, albeit with just a single table of data, can be found in my answer in [Combine Rows with duplicate values, merge cells if different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421007/combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-merge-cells-if-different/30426145#30426145)

This kind of approach is generally at least an order of magnitude faster than going back and forth to the worksheet.

Here is some code examples to get you started.  Check it out for speed.

Rename the Class Module `cLegCargoAndPassengers`
Add a worksheet to your workbook and name it `Combined`

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
Private pMission As String
Private pLeg As Long
Private pMissionData As Variant
Private pPassengers As Long
Private pCargo As Long
Private pLiftCode As String
Private pLiftCodes As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pLiftCodes = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get Mission() As String
    Mission = pMission
End Property
Public Property Let Mission(Value As String)
    pMission = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Leg() As Long
    Leg = pLeg
End Property
Public Property Let Leg(Value As Long)
    pLeg = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MissionData() As Variant
    MissionData = pMissionData
End Property
Public Property Let MissionData(Value As Variant)
    pMissionData = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Passengers() As Long
    Passengers = pPassengers
End Property
Public Property Let Passengers(Value As Long)
    pPassengers = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Cargo() As Long
    Cargo = pCargo
End Property
Public Property Let Cargo(Value As Long)
    pCargo = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LiftCode() As String
    LiftCode = pLiftCode
End Property
Public Property Let LiftCode(Value As String)
    pLiftCode = Value
End Property



Public Property Get LiftCodes() As Collection
    Set LiftCodes = pLiftCodes
End Property

Function Add(Value As String)
    LiftCodes.Add Value
End Function
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineData()
    Dim cLCP As cLegCargoAndPassengers, colLCP As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long, S As String, V() As Variant
    Dim wsFM As Worksheet, wsPAC As Worksheet, wsCOMB As Worksheet
    Dim vFM As Variant, vPAC As Variant, vCOMB() As Variant
    Dim lFirstKey As Long, lLastKey As Long, sKeys() As String

Set wsFM = Worksheets("Full Missions")
Set wsPAC = Worksheets("Passengers and Cargo")
Set wsCOMB = Worksheets("Combined")

'read data into arrays
'could calculate the last column, and/or some of the leg columns,but I hard coded them for now

With wsFM
    vFM = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=7)
End With
With wsPAC
    vPAC = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=17)
End With

'Collect and combine the data
'First get the full missions and tease out the important data

Set colLCP = New Collection
For I = 2 To UBound(vFM, 1)
    Set cLCP = New cLegCargoAndPassengers

    'Get the whole row
    'Could get each component separately, if needed
    ReDim V(1 To UBound(vFM, 2))
        For J = 1 To UBound(V)
            V(J) = vFM(I, J)
        Next J
    With cLCP
        .MissionData = V
        .Mission = Trim(Left(vFM(I, 4), InStr(1, vFM(I, 4), "_") - 1))
        .Leg = vFM(I, 5)
        colLCP.Add Item:=cLCP, Key:=.Mission & "|" & .Leg
    End With
Next I

'Now combine the Passenger and cargo data
For I = 2 To UBound(vPAC, 1)
    'Generate all possible keys
    'allows for possibility of passengers being on for more than two legs

    lFirstKey = vPAC(I, 3)
    lLastKey = vPAC(I, 4)
    ReDim sKeys(1 To lLastKey - lFirstKey)
    K = 0
    For J = lFirstKey To lLastKey - 1
        K = K + 1

        'Trim may be superfluous, but trailing space present in your sample data
        sKeys(K) = Trim(vPAC(I, 1)) & "|" & J
    Next J

    'Add the data for each leg
    For K = 1 To UBound(sKeys)
    With colLCP(sKeys(K))
        .LiftCode = vPAC(I, 17)
        .Add (.LiftCode)
        .Passengers = .Passengers + vPAC(I, 15)
        .Cargo = .Cargo + vPAC(I, 16)
    End With
    Next K
Next I

'Now Combine the data
'Row 0 for the headers
K = UBound(vFM, 2)
ReDim vCOMB(0 To colLCP.Count, 1 To K + 3)

'Populate headers
For I = 1 To K
    vCOMB(0, I) = vFM(1, I)
Next I
vCOMB(0, K + 1) = "LIFT CODE"
vCOMB(0, K + 2) = "LIFT PASSENGERS"
vCOMB(0, K + 3) = "LIFT CARGO"

'Populate data
For I = 1 To colLCP.Count
    With colLCP(I)
        V = .MissionData
        For J = 1 To UBound(V)
            vCOMB(I, J) = V(J)
        Next J

        S = ""
        For L = 1 To .LiftCodes.Count
            S = S & "," & .LiftCodes(L)
        Next L
        S = Mid(S, 2)

        vCOMB(I, K + 1) = S
        vCOMB(I, K + 2) = .Passengers
        vCOMB(I, K + 3) = .Cargo
    End With
Next I

'Write the results
With wsCOMB.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vCOMB, 1) + 1, UBound(vCOMB, 2))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vCOMB
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is certainly a good start for an answer, but I do think you really need to at least show examples of each of the four steps. Then it would be an excellent answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think the OP would be best served by doing most of that work himself, aided by the reference to Pearson's article on classes, but I'll add a few examples.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't about the OP, it's about building a library of quality questions and answers. If it helps the OP then that's a bonus, but it's not the purpose. You shouldn't make all future readers do the work themselves.

Comment: @Enigmativity In that case, I'll post a link to another question which provides an example of combining data using a collection of UDO's.

Comment: I appreciate the answer in either case. I'll look at both links and see if it gets me where I need to go with this.  I should be able to take a look on Monday when I get back to work.  //  Enigma - I also appreciate the help in expanding on the answer.  I've not worked much with arrays or creating classes.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I read through everything and I am familiar with classes from some a Java course I took.  I'm having a hard time seeing what I could do with a class that would be faster, though.  I took at look at your example answer as well.  My data sets are just too different to combine, I think.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @ineverfinishanyth Now that you've posted some data, I'll fool around with it.

Comment: @ineverfinishanyth The reason using classes and arrays is so much faster is that you don't have all those worksheet operations.  One reason to use classes in this instance is for clarity and future maintenance.  I have posted some code showing this approach.  It puts the combined result on a different worksheet which I have named `Combined` but could be easily modified to use the same worksheet.  I didn't wnat to mess up the original data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - This is great stuff.  I'm running through the code.  I hit a slight hiccup and I know the reason.  When the code gets to "With colLCP(sKeys(K)), there is a chance that an item exists in the Passengers and Cargo sheet that doesn't exist in the Full Missions sheet.  This sometimes has to do with the date range of the data pull.  It is okay to skip these items.  I know that collections don't have an Exists check, so how could I skip those that throw errors?

Comment: @ineverfinishanyth  one uses an on error resume next and check for the error code. Away now, but I'll post something she I return

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I went ahead and added it as I assumed that would be the correct fix.  I just wanted to make sure.  The code executed beautifully.  It grabbed cases of multiple lifts on a single leg and cases of single lifts on multiple legs of a mission.  It was also lightning fast, too.  Really superb work!

Comment: @ineverfinishanyth Glad it is working well for you, and that you were able to experience the speed difference between multiple worksheet accesses, vs doing as much as possible within VBA itself.  Also, once you get used to working this way, it becomes pretty easy to devise and support this kind of code.