# How to merge rows together where there are more than one columns that share the same value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to group information together with VBA in Excel where if there are any duplicate values in **Big Group column & Sub Group column** the rows will then be combine into one row.

This is how the table looks like:

```
|Big Group|Sub Group| Animals
------------------------------
| A1      | a       | raccoon     
------------------------------
| B2      | b       | dog
------------------------------
| B2      | c       | tiger
------------------------------
| B2      | c       | lion
------------------------------
| A1      | d       | deer
------------------------------
| A1      | a       | bear
------------------------------
```

I want to combine the rows to be like this:

```
|Big Group|Sub Group| Animals
-----------------------------------
| A1      | a       | raccoon; bear
-----------------------------------
| B2      | b       | dog
-----------------------------------
| B2      | c       | tiger; lion
-----------------------------------
| A1      | d       | deer
-----------------------------------
```

I have tried using this macro code. it worked, but my only problem with it is that it only combines the row if they are right next to each other:

```
Sub combi()
Dim i As Long
lastRow = 7

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
        Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value & ";" & Cells(i, 3).Value
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[Here is the table output with the macro above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb6JG.jpg) Can anybody suggest me a way to improve this macro?

Thank you,
Roody

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine Rows with duplicate values, merge cells if different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421007/combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-merge-cells-if-different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the type of consolidation code you are attempting, the data must be sorted according to your matching criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub combi()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow  As Long

    lastRow = 7

    With Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(lastRow, "C"))
        .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, _
              key2:=.Cells(1, 2), order2:=xlAscending, _
              Header:=xlNo
    End With

    For i = lastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i + 1, "A").Value And _
           Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i + 1, "B").Value Then
            Cells(i, "C").Value = Join(Array(Cells(i, "C").Value, Cells(i + 1, 3).Value), ";")
            Rows(i + 1).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If for some reason you are trying to avoid sorting the data then a comparison method that looks further than a single row offset would have to be used.

Comment: Hi @user10959770 , thank you for helping me out! I really appreciate it. 

Could you explain to me what does this particular line of code mean? 
`.Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, ` and `key2:=.Cells(1, 2), order2:=xlAscending, _`